# Некорректная работа билда через BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, build

Разрабатывается фронтенд на React. При использовании для навигации BrowserRouter билд фронта работает некорректно на страницах (компонентах) категорий и товаров - не подгружаются статичные изображения (любого расширения), при перезагрузке страницы фронт умирает, в консоль летит ошибка.

Как должно быть:

[image: как должно быть]

Как это выглядит сейчас:

[image: не грузит картинки]

А вот, что происходит при перезагрузке страницы:
[image: ошибка при перезагрузке]

Стоит отметить, что при использовании HashRouter подобных проблем с билдом не возникает. При использовании BrowserRouter проблема возникает только на залитом на хостинг билде и только на страницах категорий и товаров - на остальных страницах всё подгружается/перезагружается корректно. В чём может быть причина такой работы билда через BrowserRouter?